# Baked Red Potatoes cooked skin up or down (crisped results wanted)

Tags: baking, potatoes

Should red potatoes that are quartered be cooked skin up or down in the oven? (Oiled!)

Hoping to get delicious crisped results!

Comment: @aris please do not answer in comments, this bypasses all our quality mechanisms. If you want to give advice how to achieve the goal in the question, write an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I find that the side against the pan (for any ingredient in a roasting situation) tends to brown more readily.  So, if you want even browning, you'll have to turn your potatoes as the cook.  Beyond that, it's just personal preference.

Comment: by side do you mean skin side or the other sides

Comment: Any side against the pan will brown more quickly.

Comment: what do u recommend for crispy red potatoes

Comment: @ina use the search bar!  There is a lot of potato information on our site.